# How to create/install ember-cli custom test helpers with Ember 3?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

Before v3.0, it used to be that to make a custom test helper available to testing code, you'd import it into `tests/helpers/start-app.js`. Now that [the testing reorg with 3.0 has removed that file](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/compare/v2.18.2...v3.0.4#diff-38c489daba6d0944b67d484b3132651a), where should those imports go?

FWIW the ember-cli docs still show the old, non-existent file: https://ember-cli.com/testing#single-helper-per-file (filed a GH issue [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli.github.io/issues/211))

Answer (score 2):

The source for this change is [this RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0268-acceptance-testing-refactor.md#changes-from-current-system).
Basically you can (and should) just `import` your custom helpers.